# Display database item with DataSet to Datagridview from separated class to winform

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

My database is mysql.
i try to load database item to datagridview with DataSet. Here i have a DBConnect.cs class that looked like this in another project, in a same solution.

```
#region properties
public string property_sDataMember { get; set; }
#endregion

public void Select()
{
    #region fields
    string sqlQuery;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    #endregion

    #region initiate
    data = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    #endregion

    #region SQL Queries
    sqlQuery = "SELECT Number, Name, Gender, Age, Additional FROM master";
    #endregion

    #region execute
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, connect);
        data.SelectCommand = cmd;
        data.Fill(ds, property_sDataMember);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        CloseConnection();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And then i going to access the class from a WinForm, that i named it "Report" in another project and in the same solution. Here is my report code

```
private void btn_SelectAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    #region access properties
    clsDBConnect.property_sDataMember = "Result";
    #endregion

    clsDBConnect.Select();

    datagridview1.DataSource = ds;
    datagridview1.DataMember = clsDBConnect.property_sDataMember;
}
```

But what i get when i execute the button, i got "Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime. How to format the value before every item in the database is shown to the datagridview?
is my code to select all item is right? i kind of confuse with my own logic for now. i don't really know how to add the database to DataSet and it have own class that separated from WinForm.

**After populating my code**

Here is my DBConnect.cs (Which is in different project but in same solution)

```
public DataSet Select()
{
    #region fields
    string sqlQuery;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    #endregion

    #region SQL Queries
    sqlQuery = "SELECT NoNota, Nama, Tanggal, Tipe, Keterangan FROM master";
    #endregion

    #region execute
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    {
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, connect);
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Master");
        dataAdapter.Dispose();
        CloseConnection();
    }
    #endregion

    return ds;
}
```

Here is my Form1.cs (Which is in a different project but in a same solution)

```
private void btn_Tampil_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clsDBConnect = new DBConnect.DBConnect();

    dgv_laporan.DataSource = clsDBConnect.Select();
    dgv_laporan.DataMember = "Master";

}
```

And when i execute the button, it still give me an error that said "Unable to conver MySQL date/time to System.DateTime. Which is mean i have to format the database column format type that contain MySQL date/time to System.DateTime? or i still missing something in my code?

Comment: what's with the unnecessary regions? Please don't code like that!

Comment: @MitchWheat which one is? lol. yea, i am a newbie, i try to keep my code neat with regions, when i messed up i forget about to add some region until my code work

Comment: all of them....code is (mainly) there to be seen...

Comment: @MitchWheat hahaha. i will fix the region later, when my code is working

Comment: @l3arnon thanks for the fix :)
still no one going to help me? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your button event handler, you create a variable called `ds` and I don't see when did you populate the `DataSet` with data.  For a better answer, you should post reproducible code.

If your problem is related to class interaction, here is one of the possible solution.  Let say you have a class called `Database` with the following code:

```
class Database
{
   public DataSet GetData()
   {
      string connStr = "server=localhost;user=steven;password=12345;database=exercises;";
      MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
      DataSet result = new DataSet();
      try
      {
         conn.Open();
         MySqlDataAdapter reader = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM invoice", conn);
         reader.Fill(result, "invoice");
      }
      catch
      {
         // error handling here
      }
      finally
      {
        conn.Close();
      }
      return result;
   }
}
```

`Database.GetData()` will return a `DataSet` that can be used by your `DataGridView`.  For example, in a form, you can create button event handler like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   ...

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Database db = new Database();
      dataGridView1.DataSource = db.GetData();
      dataGridView1.DataMember = "invoice";
   }
}
```

If you want to share the instance (object) of `Database` class, you can make it a private member for `Form1` class, for example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

   private Database db = new Database();

   ...

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      dataGridView1.DataSource = db.GetData();
      dataGridView1.DataMember = "invoice";
   }
}
```

### Update Related To `Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime`

This exception is causes by *bad* data in your table.  Check any of `date` fields in your table for invalid date such as '0000-00-00'.  You can issue the following query for quick check:

```
SELECT Tanggal FROM master WHERE Tanggal = 0;
```

Replace your invalid `date` with the valid one or `NULL` value.  For example, to replace all 0 date field into NULL, use the following query:

```
UPDATE master SET Tanggal = NULL WHERE Tanggal = 0;
```

To make sure this error is not related to your code, truncate your table (empty your table!) before you run your program.

Comment: i still got "Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime.

Comment: Here is what i do after i populate my code :
*uhm.. can't write too long in comment section, going to update in my question area

Comment: The exception is related to bad data in your table.  The problem is not in your code.  See my updated answers.

Comment: Got it! thank u @newbie (pro one) hahaha. I have to find a proper way to insert date/time into database :)