# Static Methods to Select, Insert & Update Data C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, oop, datagridview

The below is a Static method written in java to populate a jtable with query of request.(Basically most queries can be executed and the method can populate the data- Includes where and joins clauses too)

Is there a similar way in C# to do this ? (Basically this method is from an external class(same package) to jframe then to jtable - So how can we do the same with C# class to Windows forms and then to data grid view).

The only good source I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930766/display-database-item-with-dataset-to-datagridview-from-separated-class-to-winfo)  but that's in mysql how can use the normal mssql methods and do this ? If someone can direct me to source that explains how to do this or give an example of how to do this with all Select, Insert & Update clauses it would be great.

```
public void searchData(JTable table, String Query) 
{        
    try 
    {    
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(Query);

        //To remove previously added rows
        while (table.getRowCount() > 0) 
        {
            ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).removeRow(0);
        }
        int columns = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        while (rs.next()) 
        {
            Object[] row = new Object[columns];
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) 
            {
                row[i - 1] = rs.getObject(i);
            }
            ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).insertRow(rs.getRow() - 1, row);
        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: Search examples on how to use the SqlDataAdapter Fill method.

Comment: Start from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter

Comment: @Steve Doesn't help as I expected but thanks any other options ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ADO.NET you build an SqlDataAdapter with your query and connection, initialize a DataTable variable instance and call the SqlDataAdapter.Fill method passing the DataTable variable. Your data is in the DataTable.

```
public DataTable searchData(string query)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(....constring here...))
        {
            using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con))
               da.Fill(table);
        }
        return table;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The DataTable returned by this method could be assigned to the DataGridView DataSource property. The grid should show your data and then you could start customizing the grid with header and formatting.